# Firebase AuthInstance.currentUser is null after successfully reload

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm currently having an issue during some of my users who log-in with email and password. The case is that after send the verification email, I'm calling `reload` in my current FirebaseUser to update the currentUser an know if the email have been verified or not.

Everything works fine at this point. The thing is that sometimes after call `reload` over an instance of `FirebaseAuth.currentUser.reload()`, on the successful callback of `reload` I'm trying to access again to the already updated `FirebaseAuth.currentUser` instance, and the funny thing is that this comes to be null and I'm getting a NPE, when the user have been successfully reloaded and the instance should be updated, not deleted.

This is my code right now:

```
 override fun verifyUser() {
        if (authInstance.currentUser == null) {
            dispatcher.dispatchOnUi(VerifyUserEmailCompleteAction(requestState = requestFailure(FirebaseUserNotFound()),
                    verified = false))
            return
        }
        RxFirebaseUser.reload(authInstance.currentUser!!)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({
                    dispatcher.dispatchOnUi(VerifyUserEmailCompleteAction(requestState = requestSuccess(),
                            verified = authInstance.currentUser!!.isEmailVerified))
                }, { error ->
                    dispatcher.dispatchOnUi(VerifyUserEmailCompleteAction(requestState = requestFailure(error),
                            verified = false))
                })
    }
```

The [RxFirebase](https://github.com/FrangSierra/RxFirebase) call is a Reactive wrapper over Firebase, but I have tried this code also using the normal `Promise` of the library and this error is happening too.

My NPE is coming on `verified= authInstance.currentUser!!.isEmailVerified` which should not be possible because I already did a check before start this call and the `reload` call have been successful.

Someone have suffer this issue and know why this could be happening? How can be the workaround for it? I could control the NPE there, but if the reload have been successful I want to update my user in my app data, not send a null instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `authInstance.currentUser` sometimes takes some time to be updated. You can move your `reload` call to the main thread on the `observeOn` to give `authInstance` more time to be updated, and also just in case add a `retry` clause to your code. It would be something like this:

```
RxFirebaseUser.reload(authInstance.currentUser!!)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .repeatUntil { authInstance.currentUser != null }
            .defaultTimeout()
            .subscribe({
                val user = authInstance.currentUser
                val emailVerified = user?.isEmailVerified ?: false
                dispatcher.dispatchOnUi(VerifyUserEmailCompleteAction(requestState = if (user == null) requestRunning() else requestSuccess(),
                        verified = emailVerified))
            }, { error ->
                dispatcher.dispatchOnUi(VerifyUserEmailCompleteAction(requestState = requestFailure(error),
                        verified = false))
            })
```